# C# WPF Dependency Property get and set methods not executed?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Just started a WPF study in combination with MVVM. I think I understand the basics of it and made a simple app with one checkbox with binding to a MainWindowViewModel class. The first version was with usage of INotifyPropertyChanged, which works like expected. The second version was with DependencyProperties, what left me with some some questions.

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MainWindowViewModel ctor");
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty? CBCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CBChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool CBChecked
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MainWindowViewModel CBChecked get");
            return (bool) GetValue(CBCheckedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MainWindowViewModel CBChecked set");
            SetValue(CBCheckedProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

<Window
    x:Class="CheckBoxWithDependencyProperty.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckBoxWithDependencyProperty" 
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:CheckBoxWithDependencyProperty.ViewModels"
    xmlns:vws="clr-namespace:CheckBoxWithDependencyProperty.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vms:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <vws:MainWindowView />
</Window>

<UserControl 
    x:Class="CheckBoxWithDependencyProperty.Views.MainWindowView"
    ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox Name="cb" IsThreeState="False" Content="First checkbox"
                  IsChecked="{Binding CBChecked}" />
        <Label />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see in this code I expect the Debug.WriteLine statements in the get and set methods of the CBChecked property to show something. But they don't! The Debug.WriteLine statement in the ctor does...

The application windows shows no binding failures, nor does the output window in VS2022. AFAIK the DataContext is okay. What could cause this?

Comment: CBChecked property is merely CLR wrapper of CBCheckedProperty DependencyProperty and not to be used when CBCheckedProperty is accessed via binding. To monitor the change of DependencyPoperty, use [PropertyChangedCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback)

Comment: There's no reason to use dependency properties in the ViewModel - just implement INotifyProperty changed, with regular properties.

Comment: RuleOfThumb: When the ViewModel uses any type of the UI framework you did something wrong. `DependencyObject` belongs to the WPF framework and violates that RoT

Comment: @emoacht, Just figured out how to implement PropertyChnagedCallback.  TX.

Comment: @Peregrine, I agree with using INotifyPropertyChanged for this. However I'm in the process of learning/exploring WPF/MVVM.

Comment: @Sir Rufo, Why should a DepencyObject not be in a ViewModel? Could you plz explain this...

Comment: A ViewModel is an abstraction of the View and should not be bound to any UI framework. This will enable the UI designer to choose whatever UI framework they like

Comment: @Sir Rufo, Thank you. Learning more and more as we speak...